# How to find suggestions about places

Tags: geolocation

You should know that in websites like Facebook it is possible to enter the name of a place in a textbox to get some suggestions. For example, typing "San" you would have as suggestions "San Francisco, San Paulo and so..."
How can I make up something like this? Do I have to implement Google Map's APIs? Sorry for ignorance, I have no experience regard this topic. Thank You :)

Comment: Do you have any data or clues about the context? For example, are the searches only in the US?

Comment: "type ahead text box" is the term for which you're looking to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JQuery for the auto completion of text box, and after when you type enter, implement the Map of the location in for site using Google Maps API
JQuery Auto Completion -> http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I know more or less how to find suggestions with auto complete... I don't know how to find suggestions just about places.
Probably I've misunderstood what you meant, sorry.

Comment: There's an extension hosted by google code, and add support in the autocompletion text box in jquery with the names of the city, also provide a little map http://code.google.com/p/geo-autocomplete/

Comment: It's what I was searching for! Thank you, I'll give you a good evaluation! :)